# Outlook cannot login to Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, sharepoint

My Outlook 2013 connects to an Office 365 account and handles mails correctly.
When I get mails from my co-workers, it shows an exclamation mark claiming that it cannot log in to Sharepoint (yet is shows information about my co-workers).

[image]

If I open the panel, it shows *Click here for log in* but it does not work:

[image]

When I open our company's Sharepoint site, I can log in without any problem. What should I do to make my Outlook log into Sharepoint?

Comment: Several different reasons listed here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/unable-to-login-to-sharepoint-in-people-pane-of/95148050-f8da-453e-9cda-45fc30232058

Comment: It was helpful but I doesn't want to disable the plugin. I just want it to work. Unfortunately I can't see any yellow exclamation marks at my accounts suggesting that it is a password error.

Comment: It may show their blank faces because they are on the email list but perhaps not their pictures because the system can not log into sharepoint. They may be something your network or system administrator may need to configure.